# How to include confusing job history on resume

Tags: resume, work-experience

I had been working in a retail store. Let's call it Walmart. Things were going very well but I got another job offer that paid better. I left on good terms, and worked at the new job for basically just the Christmas season rush. I didn't like this job as I wasn't getting breaks. I contacted my old boss at Walmart and asked if I could have my old job back. He said yes. Unfortunately, there was a miscommunication and he thought I was only asking about the following month and he had already hired someone new. So basically all of a sudden my name stopped appearing on the schedule and when I asked why he said he thought I had a new job.

For the past couple months I've been working various on-call/part time gigs.

What should I include on my resume? I had it that I am still working at Walmart because technically my boss never said I wasn't working there anymore, but I haven't worked there in a couple months. I had an interview and they asked when I can start and I said "immediately" and they said "don't you need to give Walmart notice that you're leaving and it seemed like I was trying to hide something.

Facts

1. I believe my old boss screwed me over when he said I could have my old job back but in fact he only gave me a few shifts (I quit the other job on the premise that I had the job)
2. I'm not trying to hide anything, it's just such a complicated story I don't know how to convey it on my resume or interview
3. I would like to be honest

Should I just add the date I had my last shift at Walmart to my resume? Should I include any other temp/on call work I've been doing like back ground acting and odd job's off craigslist? My goal is to show that I haven't just been sitting on my butt because I haven't.

Comment: you don't have to include every job on your job resume. I would have an "odd jobs" catch all  category (call it something more professional), put the dates you were working, and then briefly describe the places

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering you were able to summarize the situation in two paragraphs it is not that confusing.  If you want to explain it in a single sentence I would phrase it like this:

*The Walmart I work at accidentally became over staffed so at this time they are not requiring anyone give any lengthy notice if they are leaving.*

As for your other questions:

> Should I just add the date I had my last shift at Walmart to my resume?

The best solution would be to ask your manager at Walmart if he has an official termination date for you.  If he does that is what you will want to put on your resume otherwise do not list a termination date.  In the event you do not have a termination date, then once you land the new job let him know that he needs to update his records to list you as terminated.

I once fat fingered a month on an application and when they did a background check they noticed it.  Luckily it was not a big deal since it was an accident.  In your case it is best not to risk it.

> Should I include any other temp/on call work I've been doing like back ground acting and odd job's off craigslist?

Only if they are relevant to the job you are applying for or enhance the quality of your resume.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere nope, that is for when they in the interview they pose a question like the one JayT said.

Comment: Rather than "*The Walmart I work at accidentally became over staffed so at this time they are not requiring anyone give any lengthy notice if they are leaving.*" I'd go for wording more like "*I don't have any regular shifts at Walmart, and none currently scheduled; I am employed on a casual basis. As such I do not need to give any notice.*"